# Assignment problem

Tags: c#

ag = logss_EventAnalyzer.tabEventsString[0];

**ag** is a static string,

**logss_EventAnalyzer** is a class,

**tabEventString** is a static string array.

During debugging, I saw that logss_EventAnalyzer.tabEventsString[0] contains some string, but it is not assigning into ag. It's value is null.

What is the problem here and what is the solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: where is this line? Can you just paste the relevant classes?

Answer (score 1):

You say "during debugging"; does `logss_EventAnalyzer.tabEventsString[0]` contain a (non-null) string *when you assign ag*?

Note that the assignment doesn't mean that changes to `tabEventsString[0]` will be reflected in `ag`, since `string` is immutable, and any changes to `tabEventsString[0]` are actually creating *new* strings. If you want this type of behaviour, you'll need to use a member of some class:

```
public class Foo {
    public string Bar {get;set;}
}
static Foo ag;
static Foo[] tabEventsString;
...
ag = logss_EventAnalyzer.tabEventsString[0];
...
```

now `ag.Bar` will always be the same as `tabEventsString[0].Bar`

---

Also - do you perhaps have a local variable called `ag`? This would take precedence.

Can you post code that demonstrates this problem happening?

As an aside; note that both static fields and arrays have various associated complexities if your app gets complex... you might want to consider re-factoring them.

The following works fine:

```
static class logss_EventAnalyzer {
    static string[] tabEventsString = {"abc","def","ghi"};
    static string ag;   
    static void Main() {
        ag = logss_EventAnalyzer.tabEventsString[0];
        System.Console.WriteLine(ag);
    }
}
```

If you are doing something radically different, you're going to have to give us a clue...

Answer (score 0):

When you have a breakpoint at the line in question, does `ag` get a value assigned?

I suspect that in some other part of your code you're setting `ag` to null unintentionally, or perhaps you're assigning `ag` before `logss_EventAnalyzer.tabEventsString[0]` is given a non-null value.

If you give more details, I can give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first entry of logss_EventAnalyzer.tabEventsString is containing a string assigned to a null value. You have to look at the stacktrace to see which object is added as 1st entry. This object could be null assigned.